# Dart: How can I get the values of an enum in dart when I do not know at compile time which enum it will be?

Tags: dart, enums

I want to use different `enums` in a program and display the different values / options dynamically

In this example, I look at two different `enums` and I want to use them later on and show their potential values, how do I do that? But I want this to work for all `enums`, not just those two.
Here is my example:

```
enum ABC {a, b, c}

enum ThreeNumbers {one, two, three}

void main() {
  print('----');
  FancyPrint(ABC.a);
  print('----');
  FancyPrint(ThreeNumbers.two);
  print('----');
}

class FancyPrint{
  Enum input;
  
  FancyPrint(this.input){
    
    for(final v in WHATEVER_ENUM_THIS_IS.values){
      print('${v == input ? 'x' : '-'} $v');
    }
  }
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
----
x ABC.a
- ABC.b
- ABC.c
----
- ThreeNumbers.one
x ThreeNumbers.two
- ThreeNumbers.three
----
```

If I write instead of

```
final v in WHATEVER_ENUM_THIS_IS.values
```

the code

```
final v in ABC.values
```

it works for that enum, but obviously not for other enums.

So, how do I write this to get the values of any enum at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to retrieve the values of an `Enum` type dynamically.  You'd instead need to do one of:

- Make `FancyPrint` take the list of `Enum` values as an additional argument:

  ```dart
  enum ABC { a, b, c }

  enum ThreeNumbers { one, two, three }

  void fancyPrint<E extends Enum>(E input, Iterable<E> values) {
    for (final v in values) {
      print('${v == input ? 'x' : '-'} $v');
    }
  }

  void main() {
    print('----');
    fancyPrint(ABC.a, ABC.values);
    print('----');
    fancyPrint(ThreeNumbers.two, ThreeNumbers.values);
    print('----');
  }
  ```
- Make `FancyPrint` work only with a fixed set of `Enum` types.  For example, something like:

  ```dart
  void fancyPrint<E extends Enum>(E input) {
    Iterable<Object> values = switch (E) {
      ABC => ABC.values,
      ThreeNumbers => ThreeNumbers.values,
      _ => throw ArgumentError('Unrecognized Enum type: $E'),
    };

    for (final v in values) {
      print('${v == input ? 'x' : '-'} $v');
    }
  }
  ```
- Make `FancyPrint` work with a set of `Enum` types that can be built at runtime:

  ```dart
  final enumValues = <Type, Iterable<Enum>>{};

  void fancyPrint<E extends Enum>(E input) {
    var values = enumValues[E];
    if (values == null) {
      throw ArgumentError('Unrecognized Enum type: $E');
    }

    for (final v in values) {
      print('${v == input ? 'x' : '-'} $v');
    }
  }

  void main() {
    enumValues[ABC] = ABC.values;
    enumValues[ThreeNumbers] = ThreeNumbers.values;

    print('----');
    fancyPrint(ABC.a);
    print('----');
    fancyPrint(ThreeNumbers.two);
    print('----');
  }
  ```

Comment: That second bullet screams to be a pattern. :)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Oops, good call.  Moreover, it's screaming to use a `switch`-expression.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jamesdlin ! You wrote: "It's not possible to retrieve the values of an Enum type dynamically." - why, where could I learn more about the background, can you point me in the right direction to understand these limitations?

Comment: @Stephan It's the way Dart works.  Methods and properties on a class are equivalent to global functions with class-scope and aren't part of the class's interface.  Since they aren't part of the interface, there is no virtual dispatch that you can to access them dynamically at runtime.